# Sending a notification to an app. (Air)

Tags: android, ios, air, notifications

Is it possible in mobile using Air send a notification from my own server to an app installed in the device so it appears with the notification symbol?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends from what exactly you want. Notifications can be 2 types:
- Local (pushed from device)
- Remote (pushed from server to device)

In booth case you can do this in AIR. First type - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSd6d4f896b3a8801b7be2f55d138e29d5e40-8000.html

Second type - anyway you must use some Native Extensions like this http://juankpro.com/wordpress/2012/06/17/using-the-local-notification-ane-on-ios/

Comment: I need the option 2, pushed from a server to a device.

Comment: You need to use ANE. Take this one https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Push-Notification